# socketio override onclose method

Tags: node.js, sockets

need to broadcast to all his rooms when user disconnect.so i need to get socket.rooms in the server-side `disconnect` event.
but the documentation says it's imposible, because when disconnect triggers, the socket has left all rooms.

I dig into the source and found this code:

```
Socket.prototype.onclose = function(reason){
  if (!this.connected) return this;
  debug('closing socket - reason %s', reason);
  this.leaveAll();
  this.nsp.remove(this);
  this.client.remove(this);
  this.connected = false;
  this.disconnected = true;
  delete this.nsp.connected[this.id];
  this.emit('disconnect', reason);
};
```

maybe I should override this method and insert a disconnecting event,like so:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){

    var onclose = socket.onclose;
    socket.onclose = function(reason){
        this.emit('disconnecting', reason);
        onclose.apply(socket, reason);
    };

    //other logic ...
}
```

but this piece of code does not work.
need some suggestions or other solution. TKS.

**P.S.:**

node version: v0.12.3

socket.io version: "1.3.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not a smart way, but finally it works.

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){

    var onclose = socket.onclose;
    socket.onclose = function(reason){
        this.__disconnecting(reason);
        onclose.call(socket, reason);
    };

    socket.__disconnecting = function(reason){
        console.log(socket.rooms);
    };

    // other logic ...
}
```